# How to select from 'table' WHERE column = *wildcard*

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wildcard

When this code loads i want it to select everything and show it, and then be able to change the results with Ajax by altering the column row variable `$data`.

So how do i load column bbookschool with a wildcard and change it later?

```
$data = '_';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE bbookschool = '$data' ORDER BY time desc    limit 15")
```

i want to put a select list for values to be chosen which will be `$data`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"...and change it later?"* ? Do you mean dynamically? Give us an example.

Comment: what do you mean by column row?

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are deprecated and vulnerable to injection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 for more information.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes, i want to put a select list for values to be chosen which will be $data

Comment: Then I suggest you Google `"search dropdown select mysql php"` there are many questions/answers/examples that I found (just now when using those keywords) that will lead you back here on SO. One of which being [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12254915/1415724) – I don't have actual examples in my libraries to show you, but that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz LIKE '%part-of-baz%'
```

Using `LIKE` and updating you `$data` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `or` condition.  When `$data` is the empty string, then the query will select everything:

```
SELECT *
FROM ads
WHERE bbookschool = '$data' or '$data' = ''
ORDER BY time desc
limit 15;
```